# KendoScheduler change event not firing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm having trouble with the Kendo Scheduler widget.  The app is working and loading data in our app but will not fire the change event. Have copied the basic scheduler setup from the demo [into a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlesticks66/6KCJu/) and still no dice.  Need a second set of eyes, thanks.

References:

1.[Kendo Scheduler Demo w events](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/events.html)

2.[Kendo Scheduler change event doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#events-change)

```
<div id="displayEvent"></div>
<div id="apptList"></div>

==========================================

$('#apptList').kendoScheduler({
    views: [
        { type: 'day', selected: true },
        'week',
        'month'
    ],
    allDaySlot: false,
    startTime: new Date(new Date().setHours(7, 0, 0, 0)),
    selectable: true,
    change: function (e) {
        $('#displayEvent').text('Change called');
        var start = e.start; //selection start date
        var end = e.end; //selection end date
        var slots = e.slots; //list of selected slots
        var events = e.events; //list of selected Scheduler events

        var message = "change:: selection from {0:g} till {1:g}";

        if (events.length) {
            message += ". The selected event is '" + events[events.length - 1].title + "'";
        }
        $('#displayEvent').text(message);

    }

});
$('#displayEvent').text('Where are my events?');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this was a problem specific to build 2013.2.918.  I upgraded to build 2013.3.1119 and the events are now working.